# Unresolved External Symbols in Proxy DLL

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I'm trying to build a proxy DLL for 'Version.dll' but keep running into errors related to the exported functions.

```
00000000 characteristics
4A5BC9E3 time date stamp Tue Jul 14 05:27:23 2009
    0.00 version
       1 ordinal base
      15 number of functions
      15 number of names

ordinal hint RVA      name

      1    0 00001B14 GetFileVersionInfoA
      2    1 00001E40 GetFileVersionInfoByHandle
      3    2 0000193C GetFileVersionInfoExW
      4    3 00001AB4 GetFileVersionInfoSizeA
      5    4 000014E8 GetFileVersionInfoSizeExW
      6    5 000015FC GetFileVersionInfoSizeW
      7    6 00001614 GetFileVersionInfoW
      8    7 00002820 VerFindFileA
      9    8 00003F50 VerFindFileW
     10    9 00002AF0 VerInstallFileA
     11    A 000043F8 VerInstallFileW
     12    B          VerLanguageNameA (forwarded to KERNEL32.VerLanguageNameA)
     13    C          VerLanguageNameW (forwarded to KERNEL32.VerLanguageNameW)
     14    D 00001B94 VerQueryValueA
     15    E 000015E0 VerQueryValueW
```

My code looks like this:

```
extern "C"
{
    BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HANDLE hDllHandle, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpreserved)
    {
        if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
        {
            DisableThreadLibraryCalls((HMODULE)hDllHandle);

            // do stuff
        }

        return TRUE;
    }

DWORD APIENTRY Wrapper_GetFileVersionInfoSizeExA(__in DWORD dwFlags, __in LPCSTR lpwstrFilename, __out LPDWORD lpdwHandle)
    {
        return ::GetFileVersionInfoSizeExA(dwFlags, lpwstrFilename, lpdwHandle);
    }

// and so on for the rest
}
```

The exports definition file:

```
LIBRARY Version
EXPORTS
GetFileVersionInfoA=Wrapper_GetFileVersionInfoA
GetFileVersionInfoByHandle=Wrapper_GetFileVersionInfoByHandle
GetFileVersionInfoExW=Wrapper_GetFileVersionInfoExW
GetFileVersionInfoSizeA=Wrapper_GetFileVersionInfoSizeA
GetFileVersionInfoSizeExW=Wrapper_GetFileVersionInfoSizeExW
GetFileVersionInfoSizeW=Wrapper_GetFileVersionInfoSizeW
GetFileVersionInfoW=Wrapper_GetFileVersionInfoW
VerFindFileA=Wrapper_VerFindFileA
VerFindFileW=Wrapper_VerFindFileW
VerInstallFileA=Wrapper_VerInstallFileA
VerInstallFileW=Wrapper_VerInstallFileW
VerLanguageNameA=Wrapper_VerLanguageNameA
VerLanguageNameW=Wrapper_VerLanguageNameW
VerQueryValueA=Wrapper_VerQueryValueA
VerQueryValueW=Wrapper_VerQueryValueW
```

I'm using different function names to prevent prototype redefinition errors on including the Windows.h header file. Attempting to build the above generates the following errors:

```
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _GetFileVersionInfoW@16
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _VerQueryValueA@16
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _GetFileVersionInfoSizeA@8
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _VerQueryValueW@16
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _GetFileVersionInfoSizeExW@12
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _VerInstallFileA@32
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _VerInstallFileW@32
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _GetFileVersionInfoA@16
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _GetFileVersionInfoExW@20
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _GetFileVersionInfoSizeW@8
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _VerFindFileW@32
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _GetFileVersionInfoSizeExA@12
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _GetFileVersionInfoExA@20
```

This is admittedly the first time I've attempted to build a proxy DLL, so I might be missing something obvious. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linker error messages are telling you that your DLL does not provide definitions for `GetFileVersionInfoW`, `VerQueryValueA` etc. The fact that this is a proxy DLL doesn't really change things. This is the standard, classic, linker failure. You've declared a function, but not provided a definition for it.

Most likely you expect these function implementations to come from the system DLL, `Version.dll`. In which case you need to supply the appropriate import library, `version.lib`, to the linker to provide definitions.

When you encounter an error like this it is always worth reading the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6xx1b1z.aspx). It says:

> Code references something (such as a function, variable, or label) that the linker can't find in the libraries and object files.

That could not be much more clear in my view. You have referenced something that has been declared but not defined.

Comment: Ah, my apologies - I was under the impression that I'd already added the import library and thought instead that the errors had to do with the exports definition file. Didn't think to check twice.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `version.lib` to your Additional Dependencies in the Linker properties page.

Or you can add the following to your code:

```
#pragma comment(lib,"version")
```